# Spring and null pointer exception

Tags: spring, hibernate, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to do this:

```
@Controller    
public class HomeController {

        @Autowired
        private TemplatesService templatesService;    

        public final String TEST = templatesService.getUri();
```

The `getUri`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String getUri() {

        return (String) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("select uri from Templates WHERE state=1")
                .uniqueResult();
    }
```

It will work correctly, if I'll declare `TEST` in any method. But now I'm having this:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in file [C:\Users\anton\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.8.2.RELEASE\base-instance\wtpwebapps\blog\WEB-INF\classes\net\babobka\blog\controller\HomeController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [net.babobka.blog.controller.HomeController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:997)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
```

My root-context(I don't think it's helpful):

```
    <context:annotation-config />


    <context:component-scan base-package="net.babobka.blog" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                    p:name="template" />
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                    p:name="headHunter" />

            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="converter" class="net.babobka.blog.headHunter.Converter" />


    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/db/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>/WEB-INF/db/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${jdbc.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>




    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <task:annotation-driven />



    <bean id="Backupper" class="net.babobka.blog.backupper.Backupper"></bean>

    <bean id="OldDataRemoval" class="net.babobka.blog.termination.OldDataRemoval"></bean>

    <bean id="HeadHunterImport" class="net.babobka.blog.headHunter.HeadHunterImport"></bean>

    <bean id="urlForwardController"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController" />

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
    </bean>





</beans>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Paste the complete code of HomeController.

Comment: I think we see the relevant part.

Comment: Provide spring configuration and also the annotated part of the controller class

Comment: Ok. But others services works.

Comment: Also `getUri` is cached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because `templatesService` is not yet injected when you reference it to set `TEST`. Fields injection will only work after the instantiation of your Object. What you need to solve this is use `@PostConstruct` to set test.

```
@Controller    
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private TemplatesService templatesService;    

    public String test;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       this.test = templatesService.getUri();
    }
```

if you still want to use final, you can use injection by constructor and set TEST then.

```
  @Controller    
  public class HomeController {

    private TemplatesService templatesService;    

    public final String TEST;

    @Autowired
    public HomeController(TemplatesService templatesService) {
        this.templatesService = templatesService;
        this.TEST = templatesService.getUri();
    }
```

Comment: Seems nice. Could you tell me about `PostConstruct` in three words?

Comment: @Tony PostConstruct is from JSR250. There's lot of material in the internet: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmgkd.html

Comment: @Tony basically is a way to declare that your bean have some computing to do after it's created. There's `@PreDestroy` for you to use when you need to something before destroying your bean. It's important to understand the lifecycle of creation/destruction of your beans. If you need anything else, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of initialization order. Spring will inject dependencies into `@Autowired` fields after it has invoked a bean's constructor, but a field initializer is executed during object construction - and therefore before the field has been autowired. The field is therefore still `null`, which is why attempting to invoke a method throws a `NullPointerException`.

Alternatives:

- pass the `TemplatesService` by constructor injection, and assign the final field from the constructor rather than the field initializer
- continue to inject the `TemplatesService` by field injection, but move initialization of the bean into a `@PostConstruct` method. You will have to remove `final` to pacify the compiler.
- inject the TemplatesService by setter injection, and perform the necessary initialization in the setter. You will have to remove `final` to pacify the compiler.